# running docker-compose on a docker-machine

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm trying to deploy two services on a single ec2 instance with docker-machine and docker-compose.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --engine-install-url=https://web.archive.org/web/20170623081500/https://get.docker.com mymachine

docker-machine ssh mymachine -- mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/myapp

git clone https://github.com/myapp/service1.git
docker-machine scp -r ./service1 mymachine:/home/ubuntu/myapp/
rm -rf ./service1

git clone https://github.com/myapp/service2.git
docker-machine scp -r ./service2 mymachine:/home/ubuntu/myapp/
rm -rf ./service2

docker-machine env mymachine
//export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
//export DOCKER_HOST="something"
//export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="something"
//export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="mymachine"

eval $(docker-machine env mymachine)

docker-machine active
//mymachine

docker-compose -f ./docker-compose-prod.yml up -d
```

I get this error: `build path /home/ubuntu/myapp/service1 either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL.`

relevant parts of docker-compose-prod.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  service1:
    build:  /home/ubuntu/myapp/service1

  service2:
    build:  /home/ubuntu/myapp/service2
```

The path is fine when checking through ssh, it seems like docker-compose is still trying to work on my local machine, it's happy when I provide it with a build path that exists locally. Docker itself executes commands on the remote machine.

How do I get docker-compose to run on the remote docker-machine?

I'm new to this, so hopefully I'm missing something trivial.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `docker build` (including `docker-compose build`) involves a "build context". This context is all of the files you select to send from the client to the docker engine, including the Dockerfile, to perform the build. You can remove files from this context with a `.dockerignore` file.

When you run a `docker build /home/ubuntu/myapp/service1` or in your case, include that directory in the compose.yml file, you define /home/ubuntu/myapp/service1 as your build context that you send from the client to the docker engine. That engine may be local or a remote node, which in your case is the ec2 instance. From there, everything runs remotely, including any `COPY` or `ADD` commands in your Dockerfile that reference this context.

To run your build remotely, you can either leave the context on your local machine, rather than running your `rm`, or you can ssh into the ec2 instance and run the docker-compose commands locally on that machine (you may need to install docker-compose there, I'm not sure it's included in the default machine image). My preference would typically be the former since it allows easier development on the files used to build your image, and it allows the remote docker machine to be ephemeral.

Comment: thanks, makes sense. seems like I made the wrong assumption on how it's supposed to work